# Adding elements of 3 lists in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have three lists [a1 a2 a3 a4][b1 b2 b3 b4][c1 c2 c3 c4]

I want to create a new list by adding elements of each list

Result: [a1+b1+c1  a2+b2+c2  a3+b3+c3  a4+b4+c4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map):

`(map [ [a b c] -> a + b + c ] list1 list2 list3)`

Comment: @JuanDavidArredondo Bryan's code produces a list.  You have to tell NetLogo what you want to do with that list (e.g., print it).

Comment: This is a very good candidate for using the [concise syntax](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#concise-syntax) of anonymous procedures: `(map + list1 list2 list3)`.